# Help identifying the function

Tags: trigonometry, circles, graphing-functions

I plotted some raw data and it looks like it's almost a perfect circle (the first half of it).

[image]

From point **H** till point **F** we can see a nice circular curve.

What's the relationship between **H** and **F**? In other words, if there was a function of $x$, what would it be?

Comment: Would a sine with particular constants and offsets work (as well as boundaries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the point $R$ have coordinates $(r_1,r_2)$ then $H,G,A,B,C,D$ and $E$ would have coordinates of the form 
$$\big(\cos(x+r_1)+r_2,\sin(x+r_1)+r_2\big)$$

It seems though for me as $F$ is not on the circle.

Comment: Thank you, is that the parametric equation of the circle? And remember, this is just a plot, there were quite a few errors but the results point that it's a circle.

Comment: Also, how can I relate Y coordinates with respect to X? Basically, a function f(x)?

Comment: The circle is a curve and as such it is a multivalued function. You can think of it as $f(x)=(\cos x, \sin x)$ that is a function that takes a real number $x$ but gives back an ordered pair of numbers.

Comment: I was thinking of using $x = r\cdot cos(theta)$ to find $theta$ and then substituting it into $y = r\cdot sin(theta)$, how does that sound?

Comment: Sorry I should've been more clear, R and x are both known, I am looking for Y coordinates.

Comment: Nothing is simpler then, you need the second coordinate from my answer, that is $\sin(x+r_1)+r_2$

Comment: Thank you, got it!

Comment: You are more than welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The implicit equation for a circle is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$, where $(a,b)$ is the center of the circle and $r$ is the radius. You need the lower half of the circle, so you can rearrange it to get $y=-\sqrt{r^2-(x-a)^2}+b$.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciated! One more question, could I use parametric sine and cosine equations to relate H and F?

Comment: Yes, the parametric form of the equation for a circle is $(x,y)=(r\cos(t)+a,r\sin(t)+b)$